# Button not toggling colours

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This button was working until i added the toggle functionality, Could do with the toggle as its a button that submits information. It's supposed to change the colour the of the page. Any ideas? I've left the previous working button but commented it out.

```css
.hg { background-color: #5B3768; }
.hg h1 { color: #fff; }
.hg h2 { color: #fff; }
.hg h3 { color: #fff; }
.hg h4 { color: #fff; }
.hg h5 { color: #fff; }
.hg h6 { color: #fff; }
.hg p { color: #fff; }
.hg th {background: #fff; color: #5B3768;}
.hg tr {color: #fff;}

.Normal { background-color: #fff; }
.Normal h1 { color: #000; }
.Normal h2 { color: #000; }
.Normal h3 { color: #000; }
.Normal h4 { color: #000; }
.Normal h5 { color: #000; }
.Normal h6 { color: #000; }
.Normal p { color: #000; }
.Normal th {background: #ff9500; color: #fff;}
.Normal tr {color: #000;}
```

```html
<div>    
   <!-- <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="colorScheme = 'hg'">Hg Theme</button> -->
    <button toggle-button ng-model="eventData.themehg">
        <span ng-show="eventData.themehg" ng-click="colorScheme = 'hg'">HG Theme</span>
        <span ng-hide="eventData.themehg" ng-click="colorScheme = 'Normal'">HG Theme Disable</span>
    </button>
```

This works sort of, it doesn't change the colour but it adds the enable disable

Comment: JSFIDDLE Must be apprieciated

Comment: Where is toggle-button directive defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a schemeSwitcher function which will do the actual switching:

```
    $scope.toggleScheme = function (sheme) {
        switch (sheme) {
            case 'hg': $scope.colorScheme = 'hg';
                break;
            case 'hg-disabled': $scope.colorScheme = 'Normal';
                break;
        }
    };
```

Then in the HTML in `ng-click` call that function:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="toggleScheme('hg')">HG Theme</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="toggleScheme('hg-disabled')">HG Theme Disable</button>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cg8gy13j/3/